# How to easily move comma on a long number

Tags: javascript

I have this number 0.020928116469517644
And I want to get the percentage, e.g. 2% in this case. 
How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why 20% and not 2%?

Comment: Multiply a decimal by 100 to get it as a percent. To get a whole number, you can use parseInt() or toFixed()

Comment: It's a decimal point, not comma

Answer (score 2):

```
function percentage(x) {
   return Math.round(100*x) + '%'
}

answer = percentage(0.020928116469517644)
```

Also note that in this example, the percentage is 2% and not 20%

Comment: You should accept the answer if its right

Comment: Yep, one more question about this, how can I get non-approximated values?

Comment: Depends on how precise you want it. You can always omit Math.round, but then you will get: 2.0928116469517644%

Comment: For example, if you want 2 decimal digits, use: (Math.round( x * 10000 + Number.EPSILON ) / 100) + '%'